# How to access derived class fields using polymorphism in c++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

i have a simple parameter model class which derives from the base class, like this:

```
class IParams
{
    ....
};

class QEParams : public IParams
{
    ....
};
```

I also have executor class which derives from the base class containing IParams field.

```
class IExecutor
{

protected:

    IParams parameters;

public:

    virtual inline void initialize(IParams parameters) = 0;
    virtual IParams& execute() = 0;

};

class QEExec : public IExecutor
{

public:

    virtual void initialize(IParams parameters) override;
    virtual QEParams& execute() override;

};
```

Class QEExec should hold QEParams in parameters field. How to access QEParams members in QEExec class? Should I cast the type of parameters to QEParams?

Comment: If you store a base class and then explicitly need to cast that base to a dervied class you might want to overthink the whole design.

Comment: Your `QEExec` interface disagrees with your claim that it holds a `QEParams` field, since it only requires an `IParams` field in initialization. Ask yourself why the baseclass is structured the way it is and if it can't be changed. Also, when one class extends on another, that doesn't mean that derivation is the right way to code this. BTW: I'm completely ignoring the fact that you pass things by value. I assume that's just a bad example.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree, that you should probably overthink your design, here is how you do what you want to do:

If you want `parameters` to be able to house either an object of type `IParams` and of type `QEParams` the standard way to do this, is to use a pointer or parameter to base class. You cannot let `parameters` have type `IParams` and expect it to fit also an object of type `QEParams` since those two have a different memory layout (and probably a different size) so they necessarily cannot be at the same place.

It depends a bit on the structure of your code, how exactly you want to do this. If the Executor owns the parameter, the best type would be `std::unique_ptr<IParams>`. Otherwise you probably want to use either `IParams*`, `IParams&` or `std::shared_ptr<IParams>` depending on how you manage the lifetime of this object. The argument to initialize should be of the same type (and use move semantics if your working with `std::unique_ptr`).

To access `QEParams`' members, you have to use [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). But be very careful with this.